# Add and remove rows in a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have written a function for Add/Remove rows in a table, but the problem is that after adding a row, the CSS property of the table is not coming through properly. As in my input field is not coming in the center of the cell.

In the first row, it's displaying in the center of the cell (as it's hard-coded), but when I create a row using my function, the input field is displaying on the left side of the cell.

My code is:

```js
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}

function insRow() {
  //$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  // new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  x.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

```html
<table id="POITable" data-toggle="table">
  <tr>
    <th>colmn1</th>
    <th>colmn1</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><a onclick="insRow()" id="addmorePOI">Add row</a></td>
    <td><a onclick="deleteRow(this);" id="addmorePOI">Remove row</a></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please take a look at the image of how it's displaying in my dashboard. Note that I am using a Bootstrap table.

[image: Screenshot of the dashboard]

Comment: You're duplicating the element, which has `id` attributes - This is not a good practice, you should use `class` instead + You don't have a `tr` there...

Comment: Can you share generated HTMl also?

Comment: @yogendarji I have mentioned everything here which i have in the main source code except the nos of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each table data tag a similar class name and add the property in css of that class:

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing TR tags in your table body. Should be:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><a onclick="insRow()" id="addmorePOI">Add row</a></td>
        <td><a onclick="deleteRow(this);" id="addmorePOI">Remove row</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It looks like you have some padding coming from somehwere. You need to inspect the dom on the newly added element. I noticed that your other cells have 0 padding. try adding cellpadding="0" to the table tag or on each td add class="no-padding" (be sure to create a class for that!) and make sure that class gets added to each new td in a row that you add

Comment: I forgot to add here, But its already added in the main file source code.

Comment: Please see note about how you must have a class  that is adding default padding to your table cells. Try inspecting the console.